# Cannot play certain copy protected audio CDs on windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, audio

I cannot play several cd's that I have (all original and bought from the store) in my widows PC. Although they play on a cd player or hi-fi, when I insert them into my pc one of the following happens:

1. Playback doesn't automatically begin but also the CD/DVD drive does not appear so that I can right click on it and click play.
2. Audio starts to automatically play but it is heavily distorted. I have tried playing it using both Windows Media Player and Foobar 2000 but nothing changes.

This only happens with CDs of Warner music and after reading some forums I  have concluded that this issue is happening because of copy protection on these CDs.

Is there a way (another player or a setting) with which I can listen to these CDs? I find it unfair me not being able to listen to something I have bought and I can't return the records to the store because I bought them decades ago and some stores are even out of business now. Any solutions to this?

Comment: In some jurisdictions it's legal to download "backup" copies of songs you purchased on physical media from unofficial sources. Before too many readers draw the wrong conclusions: AFAIK the USA isn't one of those.

Comment: "bought them decades ago" they had drm back then?

Comment: @Moab the oldest cd I have been unable to play so far was Dream Theater's Metropolis part II which was released in 1999.

Comment: All I thought drm did back in those days was to prevent ripping or copying, not playing, strange issue,

Comment: @Moab My guess is that Warner tried to prevent copying by making the cds unplayable for any hardware with copying abilities... That's why they are playing normally in a hi-fi device or in the car.

Answer (score 1):

if your CD does not appear even in Windows explorer, different software will not solve the problem.
In my opinion the only solution is to buy an external USB CD player. since it seems to be a DRM incompatibility issue